# Como puedo restringir la entrada de datos duplicados, utilizando jQuery?

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

estoy haciendo una appWeb con Spring boot y thymeleaf, y me he encontrado con la necesidad de validar que ningún dato se repita, he estado probando, pero no encuentro la forma de evitar de enviar datos duplicados a la base.

Como podría hacerlo?

Muchas gracias

Comment: La pregunta no está muy clara: ¿con *base* te refieres a la base de datos?

Comment: Si, me refiero a la base de datos, estoy trabajando con sql server, y la pregunta es: Como puedo validar para que no lleguen datos duplicados a la base de datos, debido a que no puedo permitir que existan un dato duplicado porque me da error con mi Primary Key

Comment: Por mera lógica es imposible saber si un usuario te esta enviando datos que ya están en tu base, pero podrías antes de guardar el dato consultar a la base si el dato existe y siendo así enviar un mensaje al usuario indicando la existencia de dicho dato, también podrías crear un archivo con una copia de los datos a validar y validarlos por parte del cliente de esta manera el proceso lo trasladarías hacía el.

Comment: Estás usando Hibernate para persistir los objetos?